# Can I keep Kentico Installation Manager 7.0 and Kentico 8.0 on the same server

Tags: kentico

I have kentico installation manager KIM 7.0 and Kentico Installation Manager 8.0 on the same server. Now I am unable to install a new web application using Kentico 7.0. My question is that is it possible to have Kentico 7 and 8 on the same server ?
The folder structure created by KIM 7 is that of version 8 which looks for folder 'CMS' and results in error message as below when I try to access the site. I have deleted the entire site and database many times but I get this error every time I install new site

```
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
\\?\C:\inetpub\KenticoCMS_Main\CMS\web.config
```

I deleted the physical path from Inetpub and physical database from SQL server, removed the instance from KIM7 and made sure I do not see it in KIM8. Still when I start from fresh for this site name I get a Kentico 8 version. There must be some memory of the Kentico 8 instance somewhere which is causing this issue.

Comment: It is possible to have both Kentico 7 and 8 on the same machine. Not only web projects but also the "Program files". They have their own records in the system's registry and don't interfere with each other. So using KIM version 7 you should still be able to install Kentico 7. When you say you're unable to do so, are you getting any error during the installation? Please share more details with us...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what causes issues with KIM, but it is absolutely possible to host Kentico 7 and 8 on the same server and I saw quite a bit of such examples. 
Even now I have different versions of Kentico installed on my laptop.

Comment: I had upgraded this site from 7 to 8 and then deleted it due to some errors. Now I want to reinstall the version 7 of the site. I also deleted the associated database but for some reason it keeps installing as version 8. I am not sure where is the memory of old site coming from.

Comment: It is possible that when I uninstalled the site from KIM 7 it still had an entry in KIM 8 list of sites and that is why it keeps re-installing it as KIM8 site.

Comment: No, they share the list. To install Kentico 7, run KIM 7. To install Kentico 8, run KIM 8.

Comment: Or you can run "KenticoInstaller.exe" directly (can be found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kentico\<version>\Bin")

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have multiple versions of Kentico, KIM, KIT, etc on the same machine.  I believe the issue you're having problems with is your IIS and file system setup.

Take a look within IIS and delete any old websites you might have listed in there.  Second go to the location on your disk where the actual website files are stored and clean them up.  Thirdly, when you install your Kentico instance, make sure you check this is in the root directory of the website so don't create a virtual directory.  My guess is you have a Kentico instance in the root of one of your websites within IIS and have nested another instance of Kentico below it which will cause problems.